# Multithreaded version of transpose of multidimensional array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, multithreading, performance, numpy

Is there multithreaded version of `transpose` of multidimensional array in Python? Traditional Numpy `transpose` works only on 1 CPU thread and works too slow because of that.

My code that works too slow:

```
import numpy as np
# data is array of uint16
data = np.transpose(data, axes=(1, 2, 3, 0))
```

For `data` of shape `(16, 938, 299, 299)` it has been working for half an hour and hasn't finished yet! Also it consumed 20 GB of RAM.

Comment: Memory transfer speed is the bottleneck here, not CPU, so threading can't help.

Comment: Are you sure it's the `transpose`?  Have you tested the `np.array(data)` part alone?  Normally `transpose` returns a `view`, just changing the shape and strides.

Comment: Yes, it works fast.

Comment: Without a repeatable problem, there's no way to rally diagnose or solve this.  I've done similar to @hpaulj and it's very fast (except I don't have the memory for an array that big)

Comment: I removed obsolete `np.array(data)` at all.

Comment: Question was based on the incorrect data. CLOSED.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going push my memory usage. but compare these times

```
In [420]: timeit data = np.ones((16,100,10,20))
1.35 ms ± 41.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [422]: timeit np.transpose(data,(1,2,3,0))
1.79 µs ± 10.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Transposing an array takes a fraction of the time it takes to create it.  It's creating a view, not a copy.  Now further action, such as a reshape, on that view might force a copy.